# Where in my django app do I implement this get_client_ip() function?

Tags: python, django, geoip

I have a Custom User model that takes user ip address. **I want to add the IP address of the user upon completion of the sign up form**. **Where do I implement the below code?** I am not sure whether to put this into my forms.py or views.py file.

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

I expect to be able to save the user's ip address into my custom user table upon sign up.

Comment: You could instantiate a form with request obj. or pass the request obj only on form save.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer `forms` so that it could be easily testable. You have to pass request obj along with the other form kwarg during form initialisation or you could pass request obj on only during form save(ie. to `form.save` method).

`forms.py`

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True, request=None):
        # User creation logic
        user = super().save(commit=commit)
        if request:
            ip = get_client_ip(request)
            user.ip = ip
            if commit: user.save()
        return user
```

`views.py`

```
form = UserForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(request=self.request)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this makes more sense. I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the request object. What does request=None do?

Comment: If you pass request, then it would calculate the user ip from it (user obj saved with ip value) else it won't(ie. user obj saved w/o ip value). This would be helpful during testing where you want to save only the user and don't want to populate ip field.

Answer (score 0):

in your views.py
Inside any functions after 
def yourfunction(request):
You are good to go! 
For fun and also check if it works: 
print(get_client_ip(request))